# Spring Beans from Profiles are messed up

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

spring boot : 1.4.0.RC1

The problem that i'm having is that, if you have some `@Bean` methods defined in your Application, and you want to override those from a `@Configuration` with a test profile for instance `@Profile("test")` the beans from the test profile never gets loaded, unless you remove them from the app i.e the default profile.

I don't under stand why this is so messed up, surely there should be some kind of profile preference loading?

Like use default unless there are beans are defined with a specific profile, then use those instead.

If you use `@Component` annotations with profiles though it seems to work somewhat if you use `@Primary` in conjunction with the @Bean annotation. This seems like a hack.

I'm trying to move away from using component scan as a strategy because it's difficult to manage, instead we're creating configuration classes for each profile, and we'll have some defaults in the application that should be overridable

Any help regarding spring's autowire nightmare will be of great help

Comment: Please show the code of your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using 1.4.0.RC1, for the test scenario, you can try out the new [mocking and spying beans](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4.0-GA-Release-Notes-(WIP)#mocking-and-spying-beans) feature like:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyTest {

    @MockBean
    private RemoteService remoteService;

    @Autowired
    private Reverser reverser;

    @Test
    public void exampleTest() {
        // RemoteService has been injected into the reverser bean
        given(this.remoteService.someCall()).willReturn("mock");
        String reverse = reverser.reverseSomeCall();
        assertThat(reverse).isEqualTo("kcom");
    }
}
```

A conditional on `test` profile Configuration class containing a lots of test beans is not a good idea, and it is hard to link to the test case itself.

For cases other than test, you can initialize your default and overrideable beans just like what Spring Boot did. Configure them in `AutoConfiguration`s, which normally has lower priority than `@Configuration` class, and annotated with some condition annotation like `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`.